# ¿Cómo contar ocurrencias de valores separados por coma dentro de un campo de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo problemas para contar registros que se encuentran con coma.

Tengo esta base de datos EJEMPLO:

```
SELECT Id, Condicion FROM extintores
```

En el campo condición se guardan varios registros con coma ya que es un `checkbox` y van variando ejemplo: `Normal,roto,faltante` etc...

Lo que necesito es que me haga un `count` de manera independiente de cada dato separado por coma.

Actualmente lo veo asi

```
  ID   |         Condicion         |
|----------------------------------
|1|    |apagado,prendido,dañado,etc|
|2|    |apagado,etc,exterior  |
```

Necesito poder ver los los totales(count) de cada uno de ellos de esta manera si es posible

```
| Apagado|  prendido| dañado| etc |exterior|  
|--------|----------|-------|-----|--------|
|   2    |  1       | 1     |   1 | 1
```

y así con todo los otros datos que me restan

gracias a todos los que colaboren!

Comment: Creo que sería mucho mas fácil entender lo que estas buscando si pudieras dar un ejemplo, es decir, para un caso específico el resultado esperado. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar esta info?

Comment: marcos corregí la publicación para que se entienda mejor muchas gracias

Comment: Mi consejo para este caso seria que crees una tabla "condiciones" donde se encuentren estos valores y otra tabla "extintores_condiciones" (`relación n -> n`) donde para cada "extintor_id" puedas indicar el "condicion_id". Esto sería lo mas eficiente y quizás apropiado para el caso. Luego calcular dichos count seria trivial. Estoy seguro que se puede lograr sin modificar nada, pero el "costo" de realizar esta acción sería alto y con el tiempo no escalaría.

Comment: o sea no tengo manera de separar las comas y contar los totales de cada uno de ellos?

Comment: Seguramente si se puede, pero si vas a necesitar hacer esto periódicamente, es abismalmente mejor [normalizar los datos en las tablas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos).

Comment: yo hice esto SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Extintores WHERE Condicion like '%Normal%'; y me trae perfecto el dato  pero de 1 solo , no se como hacer con el select y poner otra columna al lado y realizar otra busqueda en la misma consulta

Comment: Para hacer eso, primero necesitas saber TODAS las posibles "condiciones". De ahí mi consejo de que crees una tabla "condiciones" la cual contendría dichas opciones. Tomate unos minutos y pensa por ejemplo: _¿como harías si necesitas desactivar/ocultar una condición? ¿como harías si necesitas renombrar una condición? ¿como harías para eliminar una condición? ¿como haces para validar que la condición es un valor aceptado? ¿como haces para agregar una nueva condición?_. Si así como esta tu sistema, hacer estas cosas no es trivial, entonces no escala.

Comment: las condiciones van a ser siempre esas 5 solamente van a variar si se agregan o no en algunos campos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sumando la existencia del *elemento* en el *conjunto*:

```
SELECT sum( find_in_set('apagado' , Condicion) >0 ) Apagado
     , sum( find_in_set('prendido', Condicion) >0 ) prendido
     , sum( find_in_set('dañado'  , Condicion) >0 ) dañado
     , sum( find_in_set('etc'     , Condicion) >0 ) etc
     , sum( find_in_set('exterior', Condicion) >0 ) exterior
  FROM extintores;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! una consulta final se puede ordenar de mayor a menor o viceversa??

Answer (score 2):

No creo que MySQL tenga un función específica para hacer lo que pides, pero creo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```sql
LENGTH(Condicion) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Condicion, ',', '')) + 1
```

En sí, la expresión cuenta el numero de comas y el  `+ 1` es por para contar el valor que no lleva coma. Sin embargo, si la columna `Condicion` lleva una comma por cada valor (e.g. `valor1,` y no `valor1`) entonces no ocuparías el `+ 1`.

Por ejemplo, `volar1,valor2` te dará `2`, mientras tanto `valor1` te dará un `1`.

Comment: Me parece que no has entendido la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En base a lo charlado en los comentarios, una solución seria la siguiente:

**Esquema de ejemplo:**

```
CREATE TABLE `Extintores` (
  Id INT,
  Condicion TEXT
);

INSERT INTO `Extintores` (`Id`, `Condicion`) VALUES
(1, 'apagado,prendido,dañado,etc'),
(2, 'apagado,etc,exterior');
```

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Extintores WHERE FIND_IN_SET('normal', Condicion)) as 'normal',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Extintores WHERE FIND_IN_SET('apagado', Condicion)) as 'apagado',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Extintores WHERE FIND_IN_SET('prendido', Condicion)) as 'prendido',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Extintores WHERE FIND_IN_SET('dañado', Condicion)) as 'dañado',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Extintores WHERE FIND_IN_SET('exterior', Condicion)) as 'exterior',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Extintores WHERE FIND_IN_SET('etc', Condicion)) as 'etc';
```

**Resultado:**

```
| normal | apagado | prendido | dañado | exterior | etc |
| ------ | ------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | --- |
| 0      | 2       | 1        | 1      | 1        | 2   |
```

[Ver en DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nkpmj7RfaecWRAF6twFm2H/0)

---

**PD**: Insisto en que considero que esta es una solución temporal y que realmente deberías [normalizar tus tablas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos).

Answer (score -1):

La unica solución buena y rapida para contar los valores que hay dentro de un campo, ya sean por comas, puntos, guiones, etc es esta:

```
    LENGTH(CampoTBL) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CampoTBL, ',', '')) + 1
```

Comment: Me parece que no has entendido la pregunta.